# Unknown Spam Backlinks Linking to my Website, affecting rankings

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks, blackhat

From the middle of February 2019, I started noticing drop in the traffic we generate for our website. I heard that some Google SE updates are around and I don't really know if my traffic drop is related to this unknown spam backlinks or due to an algorithm update.

Here is a screenshot from my GSC:

[image: Spam link from external domain]

[image: spam backlinks from multiple pages on external domain]

As you can see from the above, my website URL, the same kind of spam backlinks are also targeted at my other two websites.

**All backlinks from theses suspicious websites are targeted at my most viewed and ranked content**

> Should I disavow from these links now ? or wait till google updates finish

Answer (score 2):

If you think these backlinks are from a domain that relates to spam and are not acquired by you, it is best to do the following:

- Contact the domain webmaster to remove all the pages linking to your domain
- Disavow all the bad or low quality backlinks that you think are affecting the website

> Should I disavow from these links now ? or wait till google updates finish

Irrespective of google updating their algorithms, if you notice any bad / low quality backlinks, it is best to remove them from the domain or disavow them.